# Accept google calendar invite with iCloud calendar

Tags: icloud, calendar, ical, google-calendar

I use an iCloud calendar account for my private life, via the macOS and iOS Calendar apps, and Fantastical.

Whenever I get an invite from a friend using Google Calendar, I get an email with an invite.ics attachment. I can open the attachment using calendar to import it, but this will not notify the sender that I have accepted the invitation. I have a gmail account and can accept the invite in Google Calendar, but then it is in a separate calendar from all my other events.

Is there any way to really accept an invitation sent from Google Calendar that allows me to have the event in my iCloud calendar?

The reason is that I have shared my iCloud calendar with my partner (read-only), so they can see what I'm up to and plan accordingly – so simply showing my Google Calendar in Calendar.app doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to show both Google and iCloud calendars in the Calendar app?

Comment: No, almost the opposite. I am looking for a way to accept invites from a Google calendar user to my gmail address, while adding them to my iCloud calendar. I do not want to be forced to have some of my events in a Google calendar, but I still want to accept them (and ideally get nice updates when the event changes).

Comment: Asking the dumb question... why not just keep the personal calendar in Google along with the public one?  To be clear, I am certainly not recommending the use of GCal, but you've already made that call, so why the split?

Comment: It is not me who is using gCal, but an associate who invites me to events using their gCal. I also have an account (who doesn't?), which I prefer not to use. I have reasons for wanting my events all in my iCloud calendar, for example it is shared with my partner so they can plan more easily.